# How do I create a GUI add in for excel in visual studio?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2015, excel-addins

I want to create a GUI add-in for `Excel`, for example, a dock window on a ribbon with a windows form. What project would this be in Visual Studio? I have tried Excel add-in but I don't know if this has the GUI component I'm looking for.

I have the same question as this guy 10 years before [How do I create a GUI add in for excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7165698/3118667)
But I can't use a 10-year-old answer, so is there any contemporary feature on visual studio, which solves my problem?

Comment: Do you know how to make an excel adding to start wtih? if not, i think this questions is a little premature. You should likely do some walkthroughs and get an understanding of the technology, then if your are stuck, you show what you have, why its not working, and what you expect with any other needed information to make this a self contained well rounded question

Comment: Yes i know it. But I don't know which technology I should use to get a GUI into my add-in. With VBA this is no problem, but I want to use C# or VB in visual studio. So, what kind of "new project" shall I start in your opinion?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-adding-controls-to-a-worksheet-at-run-time-in-vsto-add-in-project?view=vs-2019 there are more examples there as well